# JIRA component strategy

Tags: components, jira

I've recently switched to JIRA from another bug tracking system, and previously we were not using the "component" field. The project was pretty small, so it didn't seem to need it at the time. As the project is getting a little bigger, I'm finding that the component field may useful, but I'm not exactly sure of how to split the components.

For example, let's say I have a banking application and I am adding a feature to transfer money between accounts. That feature might be classified as an "Accounts" component, but it also would affect the user interface, as well as have some security issues associated with it. It seems like many issues will have this cross-cutting concern.

Is there a best practice for determining how to divide a project into components? Are things like "User Interface" and "Security" too broad?

I'm not sure this question has a single correct answer, so maybe it should be moved to a community wiki, but any insight people can provide would be helpful here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Components are most useful if they have obvious default assignees for each one (component leads). Another approach is to wait for a while and use labels. See if there are common labels that your users like to use, and then create components in a few weeks for those labels.

Answer (score 5):

A user creating a bug can add multiple components when reporting the issue. So they could select Account, transfers and security issue (or Loan, Payments, and security issue) as all components effected by a particular bug. Any combination of components can be put together so that the development team knows exactly where this bug is occurring.

Comment: Right, I was just trying to get an idea of typically what level of abstraction the components are defined at, but maybe just having multiple components like this is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

We use the component field in our company mostly to cluster the issues in a meaningful way, so that reports to these components may give you feedback which part of your application development gets the most issues, or where the most changes (with the most resulting bugs) are happening. Sometimes, the components reflect the organization of a project, then the aspect of the default assignee is a valid one (as answered by @mdoar). But even then, the overview of the project is the most interesting aspect here.